# Can't connect to specific wireless

Tags: wireless

I've just upgraded from 10.04 to 12.04.
Before the upgrade, I could connect to my wireless connection. After the upgrade, I couldn't find the connection I use. However, other connections are visible. I've tried some other tactics but they've not worked for me.
Currently using a Broadcom STA driver.

All other gadgets can connect to the wireless except my laptop.

Edit: /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections is a directory is what I've got. 
I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: Try changing the SSID and see if you have any luck.  Obviously only works for a home connection.

Comment: Please restart your network using `sudo service network-manager restart` & try to check whether the AP's are visible. Also, please [**edit**](http://askubuntu.com/posts/419324/edit) your question and post the output of `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`

Comment: Restarted, AP still not visible. Others are, not mine.

Comment: My bad I missed a part of the code, sorry for that. Try `ls -l /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` & let me know whether your previous AP's are listed?

Comment: 1s command not found.

Comment: what do you mean by command not found?? could you please post a screen of what you did now?? that command should list down the existing saved AP's if there's any

Comment: I'm sorry, the existing AP got deleted. But any which way, I can't find it again.